# Meteor.js / MongoDB between dates query not returning data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have the following piece of code for getting results back from a Mongo Collection.

```
var currentDate = moment().toISOString();
// RETURNING: 2016-12-10T20:36:04.494Z

var futureDate = moment().add(10, "days").toISOString();
// RETURNING: 2016-12-20T20:36:04.495Z

return agenda = Agendas.find({
  "agendaDate": { '$gte': currentDate, '$lte': futureDate }
});
```

And the date is stored in MongoDB Collection like below;

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("584877e56466dd236cd95f15"), 
"agendaDate" : ISODate("2016-12-12T17:28:25.000+0000"), 
"agendaTime" : "20:59", 
"agendaEvent" : "Test event" 
}
```

However, I am not getting any results returning as all. I have set up 3 test documents, 2 in the range, 1 outside.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and help rectify the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compare dates against actual date objects, not strings representing them.

That is, you need to get the date from your `moment` objects, using the [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) method.

```
var futureDate = moment().add(10, "days").toDate();
```

Comment: Works. Thanks MasterAM. Selected as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually moment.toISOString() returns a string, so you can't use it to compare with date object in your mongodb query.
You should consider creating a date object for that.
Regs,
Yann